# How can I make the JustBoom DAC HAT not interfere with pin #22?

Tags: audio, pigpio

I've got the following tricky problem: I'm using pin #22 (GPIO25) of my Raspi 3B as a GPIO input and read its state by using the pigpio function `gpioSetAlertFunc (25, relay::IgnitionISR)`, where `relay::IgnitionISR` is a pointer to the function called when pigpio detects a state change. After adding a JustBoom DAC HAT sound card, the input kept on working, but once I started talking to the sound card by using the `out123_open (sound::mp3_output_handle, "alsa", NULL)` function of the mpg123 library, I stopped receiving alerts from pin #22 without getting any error messages.

The [pinout description of the sound card](https://www.justboom.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Right-Angled-Header-DAC-HAT.jpg) states pin #22 as optional (for use with an IR receiver). I don't have such a receiver soldered to the sound card, so that I don't really understand why the card interferes with a pin it isn't using anyway.

Low-level checks by using `gpio readall` and `piscope` did deliver correct resoluts: Once I pulled pin #22 to high, I received a 1, and a 0 when I pulled it to low.

Any hints? Thank you for any useful information.

Comment: I guess the HAT uses PCM.  pigpio uses PCM to time sampling so the use will clash.  If you are using the pigpio daemon try starting with the -t0 option to use PWM for timing instead of PCM.  http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/pigpiod.html

Comment: No, I am currently using pigpio directly, but for the production version of my solution, I might migrete to pigpiod. Is there also a method to switch to PWM in pigpio itself?

Comment: Yes, use http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/cif.html#gpioCfgClock **before** calling gpioInitialise().

Comment: Yep, it works. You can now make an answer out of your comment.